# Product condition in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop

My project must use product condition, it is mandatory. And since it is multi-language I currently use if condition in tpl files. However, product condition is displayed in many tpl files, and I am quite sure it is not clean/right to use this:

```
  {if $product->condition == "used"}{l s="Used"}
  {elseif $product->condition == "new"}{l s="new"}
  etc...
```

I am thinking of adding a function in core file, however as far as I know this must be done in

```
classes/product.php
```

But there is only:

```
'condition' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'values' => array('used', 'new'), 'default' => 'used'),
```

and there is no any function where condition is taken from DB depending on product id.

So, who knows what core file must be edited?

Comment: yeah, unfortunately the product condition is not translatable by default in PS 1.6... (something they thankfully changed in PS 1.7). Even the default theme uses the way you are doing it in `themes/default-bootstrap/product.tpl` starting at line 163.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your way is the only right. Because it is strongly discouraged to edit any core file. And farther more all the information for different pages is taken from a different query, so it wouldn't be so convenient to edit them also. For example for special products, it is a method `getRandomSpecial` in classes/Product.php for new products `getNewProducts` and so on. The trick is that those queries take all information from DB table product where the `condition` field is(p.*)

Comment: I agree with you, after trying to achieve it I found that I must make changes in many core files. Which can turn my presta in plenty of errors.